# Excel function for simple analysis of machine learning insight

Tags: excel

I need assistance with comparing the outputs from two different machine learning simulations. Each simulation provides results regarding detected animals in an image. The data format for the results is as follows:

- Column 1: Explanation of animals detected by Machine 1 (formatted within square brackets and double quotation marks).
- Column 2: Explanation of animals detected by Machine 2 (formatted within square brackets and double quotation marks).
- Column 3: Correct answers for the animals in the image (formatted within square brackets and single quotation marks).

If multiple animals are detected, they are separated by commas and spaces. For example:

```
["chicken"]     ["chicken", "cow"]     ['chicken wing', 'cow feet']
```

I aim to determine the overlabel and underlabel for each image based on the differences between the machine outputs and the correct answers. The expected result should be as follows:

- For underlabel: Identify animals present in the correct answers but not detected by either machine 1 or machine 2.
- For overlabel: Identify animals detected by either machine 1 or machine 2 but not present in the correct answers.

For instance:

- Underlabel: **`['chicken']`** if neither machine detected chicken.
- Overlabel: **`['cow']`** if either machine incorrectly detected cow when the correct answer was only chicken.
- Overlabel: **`['chicken', 'cow']`** if both machines failed to recognize any animal in the image, leading to an overlabel for chicken and cow.

I am seeking assistance in formulating the formulas for calculating overlabel and underlabel based on the given criteria. Thank you for your help!

for extra references this is the result I was expecting in this image:

[image]

Comment: Why Excel? I mean, the output of these simulations looks like were generated with Ptyhon and probably it would be easier to do this in Python because the structures look like lists. Anyways, about Excel, what have you tried? What formulas have you developed?

Comment: I am new to these analysis and tools (still learning) so I was trying to develop this on excel using this formula but it does not produce the expected result

for overlabel
`=IF(LEN(A4&B4&C4)>0, IF(ISERROR(FIND(C4, SUBSTITUTE(A4&B4&C4, " ", ""))), C4, ""), ""))

for under label
`=IF(LEN(A4&B4&C4)>0, IF(ISERROR(FIND(C4, SUBSTITUTE(A4&B4&C4, " ", ""))), "", C4), "")`

Happy to hear if you have any guide on doing this that is beginner friendly (I have entry level python knowledge)